# Linux/Unix check if VPN connection is Active/Up

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, ssh, vpn

I have a code which detects if OpenVPN connection is up or down:

```
if echo 'ifconfig tun0' | grep -q "00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00"
then
echo "VPN up"
else
echo "VPN down"
fi
exit 0
```

now I'm trying to re-write the code to work with PPTP or IPSEC connection. I've tried to do:

```
if echo 'ifconfig ppp0' | grep -q "00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00"
```

or the same with ipsec but does not work. Is there any other way to detect PPTP or IPSEC connection?

Comment: That `echo` usage is strange. Should those be backticks?

Comment: It's not that strange a full code is here: `if echo 'ifconfig tun0' | grep -q "00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00"
then
echo "VPN up"
else
echo 1 > /usr/syno/etc/synovpnclient/vpnc_connecting
synovpnc reconnect --protocol=openvpn --name=XXXXXX
fi
exit 0`

Comment: so basically I need to reconnect VPN once is down...the re-connection script works fine but I'm struggling with the "if"

Comment: To anyone who ever sees this question, `if echo 'ifconfig tun0' | grep -q "00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00"` means: *check if the string "ifconfig tun0" contains the string "00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00"*. A correct example would be `if ifconfig tun0 | grep -q "00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00"` (no echo, no single quotes), which means: *run `ifconfig tun0` and then check for the string from its output*.

Comment: Your regular expression can be simplified: `ifconfig ppp0 |egrep -q '(00-){15}00'`

Answer (score 3):

That `echo` statement is erroneous.  As @unwind says, the single quotes (') should be backtics (`).  Your current code is sending the literal value `ifconfig ppp0` to grep, which doesn't do anything useful.

But you don't actually need the backtics, either.  You can just send the output of `ifconfig` to `grep` directory; using `echo` doesn't get you anything:

```
if ifconfig ppp0 | grep -q "00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00"; then
  echo ppp connection is up
fi
```

Comment: in your example I'm getting "ifconfig: ppp0: error fetching interface information: Device not found" when there is no vpn and nothing where is vpn connection.

Comment: in my case it is tun0 instead of ppp0

Answer (score 3):

The following script will:

- Run the ISPConnectivity.sh script every 5 minutes.  This will mean that the VPN tunnel will not be down for more than 5 minutes.
- Check if the tun interface is down, and start the vpn script if it is.
- Check connectivity if the tun0 interface is up.  It does ping tests on 2 Public IPs  (if I get even a single response from 1 of the IPs tested, I consider this a success ), and all have to fail to run the vpn script.  I ran ping tests on multiple hosts to prevent the vpn script from starting in case the ping test failed on 1 IP.
- Send all failure output to a file in my home directory.  I do not need to see if any test succeeded.

Contents of sudo crontab:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/userXXX/ISPConnectivity.sh >> /home/userXXX/ISPConnectivity.log 2>&1
```

Contents of ISPConnectivity.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash 

# add ip / hostname separated by white space
#HOSTS="1.2.3.4"
HOSTS="8.8.8.8 4.2.2.4"
# no ping request
totalcount=0
COUNT=4

DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S`

if ! /sbin/ifconfig tun0 | grep -q "00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00"
then
        echo $DATE      tun0 down
        sudo /home/userXXX/startVPN.sh start
else

        for myHost in $HOSTS;
        do
                count=`ping -c $COUNT $myHost | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | awk '{ print $1 }'`
                totalcount=$(($totalcount + $count))
        done

        if [ $totalcount -eq 0 ]
        then
                echo $DATE      $totalcount "fail"
                sudo /home/userXXX/startVPN.sh start
        #else
        #       echo $DATE      $totalcount "pass"
        fi
fi
```

Comment: What is in the startVPN.sh script?

Answer (score 3):

You can also check with the nmcli command, to check if VPN is running or not.

> nmcli c show  --active | grep vpn

Comment: Great if using `nmcli` although I had to grep for `tun` (presumably for tunnel)

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually looking into more flexible solution eg:

```
MyIP=$(curl http://api.ipify.org/?format=text)
if [ "$MyIP" != "MYORYGINALIP" ]
then
    echo "IPSEC VPN is Running -  " $MyIP
else
    echo "IPSEC VPN is Not Running - " $MyIP
fi
exit 0
```

what about that? can I improve it any way?

Comment: It would only work if you have a static IP address, I wouldn't call it exactly a flexible solution.

Answer (score -2):

ip route list table 220    if Ip address shown -> VPN connection established, none -> no VPN

or

if [ "0" == `ifconfig | grep wlan0 | wc -l` ]; then echo "NO wlan0 has no VPN"; else echo "YES wlan0 has VPN"; fi